# Query array of subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

I have a chatRooms collections like following:

```
{ "name" : "Room1", "users" : [  {  "userId" : 1 },  {  "userId" : 2 } ] }
{ "name" : "Room2", "users" : [  {  "userId" : 1 },  {  "userId" : 4 } ] }
{ "name" : "Room3", "users" : [  {  "userId" : 2 },  {  "userId" : 3 } ] }
{ "name" : "Room4", "users" : [  {  "userId" : 2 },  {  "userId" : 1 } ] }
```

Now I want the Room(s) where userId 1 and 2 is in.
I should get Room 1 and 4.

I tried different things like

```
db.chatRooms.find({users: {$elemMatch: {userId: 1, userId: 2}}})
```

But nothing is working. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator

```
db.chatRooms.find({users: 
    {$all : [
       {$elemMatch: {userId: 1}}
      ,{$elemMatch: {userId: 2}}
    ]}
})
```

Simplified version

```
db.coll.find({users: 
    {$all : [
       {userId: 1}
      ,{userId: 2}
    ]}
})
```

Comment: You can also use dot-notation: `db.foobar.find( { 'users.userId': { $all : [ 1, 2  ] } } )`

Comment: @i80and, you solution is better ;)